# Google Street View Marker above street level

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Is there a way using Google Street View API to display Markers above the street level? I mean, if I want to place a Marker on a tree or a window of a building, staying on same lat,lng location. Likely if adding an altitude property.

Perphaps someone has already solved it writing a custom OverlayView?

I’d appreciate any help or direction with this.
Thanks